PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied When Running sqllineage Command in Node.js
I'm encountering a PermissionError while attempting to use the sqllineage command from within my Node.js application in deployment server in windows 10. Below is the code I'm using.
function analyzeLineage(callback) {
    // Execute sqllineage command with the SQL query directly
    const demoQuery = `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE user_orders AS SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, u.email, o.order_id, o.order_date FROM users u JOIN orders o ON u.user_id = o.user_id;`
    exec(`sqllineage -e "${demoQuery}"`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`Error: ${stderr}`);
            callback(error, null);
            logger.log({
                level: "error",
                message: `sqllineage -e analyze lineage : ${error}`,
            });
            return;
        }
        callback(null, stdout);
    });
}

I'm using sqllineage version 1.5.3. when I tried to execute this command through terminal, It works perfectly at the same location where my project is located but not working from code side.
Here’s the full error message I’m receiving:

{"level":"error","message":"sqllineage -e analyze lineage : Error:
Command failed: sqllineage -e "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE user_orders AS
SELECT      u.user_id,     u.user_name,     u.email,     o.order_id,
o.order_date FROM users u JOIN orders o ON u.user_id =
o.user_id;"\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main\r\n  File "", line 88, in _run_code\r\n  File "C:\Program
Files\Python312\Scripts\sqllineage.exe\main.py", line 7, in
\r\n  File "C:\Program
Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqllineage\cli.py", line 127,
in main\r\n    runner.print_table_lineage()\r\n  File "C:\Program
Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqllineage\runner.py", line
179, in print_table_lineage\r\n    print(str(self))\r\n
^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File "C:\Program
Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqllineage\runner.py", line
26, in wrapper\r\n    self._eval()\r\n  File "C:\Program
Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqllineage\runner.py", line
199, in _eval\r\n    stmt_holder = analyzer.analyze(stmt,
session.metadata_provider)\r\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File
"C:\Program
Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqllineage\core\parser\sqlfluff\analyzer.py",
line 52, in analyze\r\n    statement_segments =
self._list_specific_statement_segment(sql)\r\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File "C:\Program
Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqllineage\core\parser\sqlfluff\analyzer.py",
line 83, in _list_specific_statement_segment\r\n
config=FluffConfig.from_root(overrides={"dialect":
self._dialect})\r\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File
"C:\Program
Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlfluff\core\config.py",
line 873, in from_root\r\n    c = loader.load_config_up_to_path(\r\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File "C:\Program
Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlfluff\core\config.py",
line 684, in load_config_up_to_path\r\n    user_config =
self.load_user_config() if not ignore_local_config else {}\r\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File "C:\Program
Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlfluff\core\config.py",
line 672, in load_user_config\r\n    return
self.load_config_at_path(user_home_path)\r\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File "C:\Program
Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlfluff\core\config.py",
line 611, in load_config_at_path\r\n    d =
os.listdir(os.path.expanduser(p))\r\n
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\nPermissionError: [WinError 5]
Access is denied:
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config'\r\n","timestamp":"2024-09-03
10:44:56"}

I have tried below steps:

I have tried to change the "sqllineage" with location where sqllineage is located in my system. But still not working.

I also tried to run this command as administrator in the code.

Also checked the permission to allow sqllineage.exe to Run & execute.


